# Win Phone 7: How can I get this destination file/folder error to stop showing up?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Every now and then I get this error that says:

> Could not copy the file
>   "C:\Users\MyUserName\documents\visual
>   studio
>   2010\Projects\MyProject\MyProject\MyProject\"
>   to the destination file "bin\Windows
>   Phone\Debug\", because the destination
>   is a folder instead of a file. To copy
>   the source file into a folder,
>   consider using the DestinationFolder
>   parameter instead of DestinationFiles.

If I just do a rebuild, it goes away, but it's pretty annoying. Why is this happening, and how can I get it to stop?

Comment: Is this only happening for one project or for others too?

Comment: It happens in all of my Windows Phone 7 Game projects.

Answer (score 1):

I just started seeing this.  Simply right click on the solution node and choose "clean solution".  That worked for me.